# Unauthorized with local Nexus repository

Tags: bazel

I have a local Nexus repository, I declared Nexus repository as below image with username and password in link, but when I build, it logs "unauthorized...".

[image]

Comment: Did you write your username and password, or literally `{username}` and `{password}` like visible on the screenshot?

Comment: In reality, I wrote username and password clearly